# How to use partials in Slim templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, slim-lang

Is there any way to have `_header.slim` and `_footer.slim` in separate files and inject them into other (main) `slim` files?

I'm building templates like:

```
def slim(template, context = nil)
  Slim::Template.new { template }.render(context)
end

def template(name)
  File.read(Notifications.root.join "notifications/templates/#{name}.slim")
end
```

When I inject either `slim('_header.slim')` or just `template('_header.slim')` it's render as a plaintext in my main layout.

Any way to do that?

Comment: you can try using `html_safe` to see the html output rather then plan text.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for that was so simple.

#### Output without HTML escaping `==`

Same as the single equal sign (`=`), but does not go through the `escape_html` method. For trailing or leading whitespace the modifiers `>` and `<` are supported.

- Output without HTML escaping and trailing white space `==>`. Same as the double equal sign (`==`), except that it adds a trailing white space. The legacy syntax `=='` is also supported.
- Output without HTML escaping and leading white space `==<`. Same as the double equal sign (`==`), except that it adds a leading white space.

https://github.com/slim-template/slim#output-without-html-escaping-